# Python - How to fit a Polynomial Features Transformation in a 3D scatterplot?

Tags: python, linear-regression, polynomials

I'm trying to plot a curve fit line in a 3D scatterplot but I keep getting an error when trying to plot the line of best fit that is predicted by the model. I have to use the following x_fit and y_fit data to compute z_fit by invoking the model's predict() method.  The points are x,y,z.

Small sample of the data:

x = [-3.319120, 8.812980, -19.995425, -7.906697,-14.129764]

y = [-2.070820, 8.055306, -19.407131, -7.559838,-12.762732]

z = [-12.762732, 109.527857, 4867.408412, -149.039706,1493.048153]

This is my code:

```
x = df['x']
y = df['y']
z = df['z']
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
features = np.array(df[['x','y']])
response = np.array(df[['z']])
                    
poly_features= PolynomialFeatures(degree=3, include_bias=False)
x_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(features, response)
features[0]
x_poly[0]

#Train Linear Regression Model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_poly, response)

# Plot Curve Fit
x_fit = np.linspace(-21,21,1000).reshape(-1,1)
y_fit = x_fit

x_fit_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(x_fit, y_fit )
z_fit = model.predict(x_fit_poly)

ax=fig.add_subplot(2,2,1, projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(x,y,z, c=z, cmap='jet')
ax.set_xlabel('x',c='r', size=12)
ax.set_ylabel('y',c='r', size=12)
ax.set_zlabel('z',c='r', size=12)
#plot the line
ax.plot3D(x_fit,y_fit, z_fit, 'black')
ax.view_init(0,90)
```

Output:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [119], in <cell line: 6>()
      3 y_fit = x_fit
      5 x_fit_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(x_fit, y_fit )
----> 6 z_fit = model.predict(x_fit_poly)

ValueError: X has 3 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 9 features as input.
```

Expected output:

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: error shows problem with `model.predict()`, not with `scatterplot`. You creates wrong `x_fit_poly`. I think you may need `.transform([fit_x, fit_y])` instead of `fit_transform()`

Comment: I am aware of that. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: better add some example data to code so we could run it.

Comment: I think you may need `poly_features.transform([fit_x, fit_y])` (or maybe `poly_features.predict([fit_x, fit_y])`) instead of `fit_transform(fit_x, fit_y)`. At start you use `poly_features.fit_transform(features, response)` where `features` is `df[['x','y']]` and `response` is `df[z]` - so you have something like `poly_features..fit_transform([x,y], z)` so next `fit_transform()` would also need something like `[x,y], z`. But `fit` is for training data but you don't need to train it but trasform or predict new values.

Comment: That didn't work either. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fit` is for training data (and it uses `fit_transform()` with data `([x, y], z)` to train and transform data) but later you need only `transform([x, y])` to make transformation without traning.

```
x_fit = np.linspace(-21, 21, 1000).reshape(-1,1)
y_fit = x_fit

arr = np.hstack([x_fit, y_fit])
#print('arr:', arr.shape)  # (1000, 2)

x_fit_poly = poly_features.transform(arr)

z_fit = model.predict(x_fit_poly)
```

And this should resolve this problem with `ValueError: X has 3 features,` but you still may have problem with next lines of code.

---

Full code for test:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'x': [-3.319120, 8.812980, -19.995425, -7.906697,-14.129764],
  'y': [-2.070820, 8.055306, -19.407131, -7.559838,-12.762732],
  'z': [-12.762732, 109.527857, 4867.408412, -149.039706,1493.048153],
)

features = np.array(df[['x','y']])
response = np.array(df[['z']])
print('features:', features.shape)
print('response:', response.shape)

poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3, include_bias=False)
x_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(features, response)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_poly, response)

x_fit = np.linspace(-21, 21, 1000).reshape(-1, 1)
y_fit = x_fit

arr = np.hstack([x_fit, y_fit])
print('arr:', arr.shape)

print('transform')
x_fit_poly = poly_features.transform(arr)

print('predict')
z_fit = model.predict(x_fit_poly)
print('z_fit:', z_fit.shape)

x = df['x']
y = df['y']
z = df['z']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c=z, cmap='jet')
ax.set_xlabel('x', c='r', size=12)
ax.set_ylabel('y', c='r', size=12)
ax.set_zlabel('z', c='r', size=12)

#plot the line
ax.plot3D(x_fit.flatten(), y_fit.flatten(), z_fit.flatten(), 'black')
ax.view_init(0, 90)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: When I tried that I got this error `ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[-21.         -20.95795796 -20.91591592 ...  20.91591592  20.95795796
  21.        ].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`

Comment: I added full code. Maybe you use different data.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Can you please explain what you did so I can understand this better?

Comment: I already examplained it in answer and in comment before - you have to use `transform()` instead of `fit_transform()` - `fit_transform` is for training data (and transofromating result)  and it needs `([x, y], z)`  but you don't want to train it again but only get new result for new `[x, y]`.